# Can anyone help me to detach expo app

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I have little bit queries about detach expo app :

Am done app requirement but i have one thing that support only react native.
So i read about detach expo app and i think its mean if you done your coding in expo app and after detach you got android or ios folder and then copy these two folder and paste into react native project and then run command npm install.
But in above query i have one question in my mind .
Is expo coding that i done is available and its working as expo app in react native app or not ?
And now am continue coding after detach expo app in react native like add native module in react native app.

Comment: once you eject it you do not have longer access to expo functions.

Answer (score 1):

Detach or in actual terms, ejecting of your expo, in a React-Native project is a one way function. You cannot go back to the original setup once you eject.
After you eject, you get vanilla react native structure, which means separate folders for iOS and Android. This also means you lose access to expo API's you previously used. You can code or keep working on your project the same way as you were working before ejecting the app. Only your expo API's will change(if you have made use of them). Rest of your work flow will remain the same.